# nodejs installation error i cannot understand how to resolve this npm problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, monodevelop, npx, npm-live-server

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! https://aka.ms/PSWindows

PS C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\internship\stackoverflow_clone> npx create-react-app my-app
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-05T14_03_46_351Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\internship\stackoverflow_clone>
```

how to solve this?

Comment: Install nodejs at first from official nodejs download page, then try create-react-app